# Photoshop equivalent to Illustrator offset command

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, cs6, technique

I have the following image...

[image: Horse's head]

...that I'm trying to get a vector outline for in a similar way to the Illustrator Offset command.

I'm looking to have a finished **vector** look similar to this...

[image: Horse's head with vector offset shape]

*(Note: This is simply a stroke layer style that has been added to the original)*

The two outlines must be vector shapes.

Is there anything in PhotoShop that will allow me to do this?

Comment: @joojaa: Unfortunately we don't have Illustrator.

Comment: Okay - this is actually a duplicate, so I've voted to close my own question.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a few steps, but this can be automated with actions.
• Make a copy of the layer. 
• Create a stroke effect in the Layer Style panel to provide the offset. 
• Rasterize the layer to flatten the effect.
• CTRL+click the layer to select the active pixels.
• From the Paths panel's flyout menu, select "Make work path..."
• Set the tolerance as needed (lower for more detail) and click OK.

That will provide an offset vector shape. You can then delete the copied layer.

Comment: Thanks 13ruce, but this only went so far to answering my question.  I've actually found what I was looking for on the site and marked my own question as duplicate.

Comment: You're right. The other answer is better. Thanks for the consolation vote! :)

Comment: Though this process did get me so far along the path - your answer did help.